# External Hard Drive in unknown state, spins fine and head moves fine

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Laptop was on overnight and my external HDD plugged in, I woke up and heard strange clicking noises coming from the HDD. It was just spinning non-stop and the head making click noises.

The Disk Management shows unknown state for the HDD and I opened the covers and recorded a video of it:

https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/596628982

When I plug it in, it spins and the head moves fine but then stops completely and after a few minutes the disk starts spinning non-stop and head keeps moving non-stop.

This is a 2013 model, so it worked for about 8 years, is it safe to say that it's gone dead and nothing can be done about it?

Comment: Your video is BADA$$ but ***you do realize that you ruined the drive by opening it up*** *right*?  If you did have a hope of fixing it, you canceled that when you opened the cover and let dust in.  I guess it doesn't really matter though.. you have already experienced the [click of death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death) .. look down on link to hdd.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - at least it’s now in a **known** state… dead ;)